# Raster display problem

Tags: qgis, raster, zoom

When I zoom too much on a raster the layer does not appear anymore.

How to make it appear anyway?

Comment: How much is too much? Are you seeing less than a pixel? How big are your pixels in the raster and how far zoomed in are you?

Comment: Do you have a local raster file that is located on your local disc? Or do you use a webservice like OpenStreetMap?

Comment: I'm using a raster from a wms server and zoom to a scale of 1: 1000

Comment: You should add that info about wms into the question.

Comment: That's a limit built into the WMS. Note that the S in WMS stands for "service" - you don't actually have a raster, you just have temporary access to someone else's raster, and you're limited by whatever way that service is set up. You should download a raster if you want better control over it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have Scale Dependent Visibility set on your raster layer. Have a look under the Rendering tab of the Layer Properties dialog of your raster layer and make sure that the check box for Scale Dependent Visibility is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already tried to vary this parameter and it does not work. I'm using a raster that comes from a wms link